# CSR's when plugging in an existing CA into Istio

Tags: istio

I'm looking at "plugging in an existing CA" into my Istio environment as documented here:

https://istio.io/pt-br/docs/tasks/security/citadel-config/plugin-ca-cert/

I can see that the following command allows you to store a key, cert & chain to Kubernetes secrets, however it does not appear to provide an option for creating a CSR. Obviously, this would also involve first generating a private key.

Is this correct, or is there an option to do this?

```
$ kubectl create secret generic cacerts -n istio-system --from-file=samples/certs/ca-cert.pem \
    --from-file=samples/certs/ca-key.pem --from-file=samples/certs/root-cert.pem \
    --from-file=samples/certs/cert-chain.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

The command You listed allows You to create a `secret` object in kubernetes for the `CA` certificate, key, chain etc. Which can be consumed by deployments and services for use. So assumption in documentation is that You already have a certificate ready for use.

I suggest following entire istio SDS secure gateway configuration [guide](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/).

---

To generate a private key and `CSR` using `OpenSSL` follow [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/#generate-client-and-server-certificates-and-keys) documentation guide:

> For this task you can use your favorite tool to generate certificates and keys. The commands below use openssl
>   Create a root certificate and private key to sign the certificates for your services:
>
> ```
> $ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj '/O=example Inc./CN=example.com' -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.crt
> ```
>
> Create a certificate and a private key for httpbin.example.com:
>
> ```
> $ openssl req -out httpbin.example.com.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout httpbin.example.com.key -subj "/CN=httpbin.example.com/O=httpbin organization"
> $ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA example.com.crt -CAkey example.com.key -set_serial 0 -in httpbin.example.com.csr -out httpbin.example.com.crt
> ```

Additional information from istio documentation:
https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#pki

Hope it helps.